# python multiprocessing returns None, does not share counters

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having a hard time understanding how to set up shared counters so that i can get a combined result of all the processes that were run by the multiprocessing module.

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import multiprocessing

def glastvalueFetch(howfarback):
    mylist = []
    justadd = int(1) + int(howfarback)
    return(justadd)

def glvfResults():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        for howfarback in range(1,8):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=glastvalueFetch, args=(howfarback,))
            p.start()
            p.join()

print glvfResults()
```

Now, when I run this code I get back:

```
None
```

Is there a straightforward way to resolve this?

Comment: Function `glvfResults` does not return anything so it returns `None`. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import multiprocessing


def glastvalueFetch(howfarback, results):
    mylist = []
    justadd = int(1) + int(howfarback)
    results.put(justadd)


def glvfResults():
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for howfarback in range(1, 8):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=glastvalueFetch, args=(howfarback, results, ))
        p.start()
        p.join()
    while not results.empty():
        print results.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    glvfResults()
```

**Output**

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```